# How to use column containing values as dataframe column headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df:

```
 Field     Value
  Name      Fred
   Age        69
Gender         M
```

I want to use the values in 'Field' as the new dataframe column headers to have a df shaped like so:

```
Name    Age    Gender   
Fred     69         M
```

Right now I call

```py
df.pivot(columns='Field', values='Value')
```

but that leaves me with a dataframe of multiple rows containing all NaN values except for one value for that specific row (such as Name).

Comment: this example is so small it's hard to know how the reshape is actually happening. For example, `df.set_index('Field').T` fits the bar for this example. can you include a couple more rows/columns so we understand what's actually happening in the reshape? I assume you don't just have a single 1:1 mapping between Field and Value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and transposition (`.T`):

```py
In [4]: import pandas as pd
   ...:
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame(
   ...:     {
   ...:         "Field": ("Name", "Age", "Gender"),
   ...:         "Value": ("Fred", 69, "M"),
   ...:     }
   ...: )

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
    Field Value
0    Name  Fred
1     Age    69
2  Gender     M

In [6]: df.set_index("Field")
Out[6]:
       Value
Field
Name    Fred
Age       69
Gender     M

In [7]: df.set_index("Field").T
Out[7]:
Field  Name Age Gender
Value  Fred  69      M
```

To get rid of the index column do:

```
In [8]: df.set_index("Field").T.reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(columns="")
Out[8]:
   Name Age Gender
0  Fred  69      M
```

Comment: This will set Field/Value as the index column, but I don't want those in the final df... is there a way around this?